# export CVS repository

Tags: export, cvs

how to export a CVS repository from one machine to another? Would it work if i transfer the whole CVSROOT then make it the CVSROOT of the new machine? if so, would it also include all the revision history? or there are additional directories need to be exported...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good step by step guide: http://www.solarorange.com/docs/cvs/repositorymove.html
It looks like you just zip it up.